# File not found Issue with Spring project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websphere

I am trying to get a simple Spring project up and running but it doesn't seem to work. There are no errors. Tried changing various things but no luck. Below are the classes

**AppInitializer.java**

```
package com.spring.config;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {  

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    // Create the 'root' Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.scan("com.spring");

    // Manages the lifecycle of the root application context
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    // Declare dispatcher servlet. Handles requests into the application
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
            new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");



}



}
```

**WebAppContextConfig.java**

```
   package com.spring.config;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.spring")
public class WebAppContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver configureInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/scripts/**").addResourceLocations("/scripts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/fonts/**").addResourceLocations("/fonts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/vendor/**").addResourceLocations("/vendor/**");
    }

}
```

**AppConfig.java`**

```
package com.spring.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration

public class AppConfig {

}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.spring.controller;

   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
  public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String showIndex() {
    return "Hello world";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/statuscheck", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String getStatusCheck() {
    return "SUCCESS";
}



  }
```

**pom.xml**

I got spring-context (4.3.0-RELEASE), spring-webmvc (4.3.0-RELEASE), javax.servlet-api, jstl as dependencies.

I am using websphere 8.5.5.9

I tried checking this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringProject/statuscheck
```

and I got

```
[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /statuscheck
```

***EDIT-1***

I have this in server.xml

```
  <webApplication id="SpringProject" contextRoot = "SpringProject" location="SpringProject.war" name="SpringProject"/>
```

***EDIT-2***

I got this code in pom.xml .So I don't have web.xml

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
<version>2.4</version> 
   <configuration>      
<warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirector‌​y>    
<warName>SpringProject</warName> 
<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> 
   </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

***EDIT-3***

This is log file. I don't see any issues in log

```
[3/20/17 15:29:25:666 CDT] 00000001 id=         com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           I CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 4.637 seconds
[3/20/17 15:29:32:064 CDT] 0000001d id=         com.ibm.ws.security.ready.internal.SecurityReadyServiceImpl  I CWWKS0007I: The security service is starting...
[3/20/17 15:29:32:089 CDT] 0000001d id=         ibm.ws.security.registry.basic.internal.DynamicBasicRegistry W CWWKS3103W: There are no users defined for the BasicRegistry configuration of ID basic.
[3/20/17 15:29:32:524 CDT] 0000001d id=         com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.AuthConfigFactoryWrapper           I CWWKS1655I: The default Java Authentication SPI for Containers (JASPIC) AuthConfigFactory class com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.ProviderRegistry is being used because the Java security property authconfigprovider.factory is not set. 
[3/20/17 15:29:32:555 CDT] 0000001d id=         com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.monitor.DropinMonitor        A CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[3/20/17 15:29:32:585 CDT] 0000003c id=         com.ibm.ws.security.ready.internal.SecurityReadyServiceImpl  I CWWKS0008I: The security service is ready.
[3/20/17 15:29:32:586 CDT] 0000003c id=         com.ibm.ws.security.token.ltpa.internal.LTPAKeyCreator       I CWWKS4105I: LTPA configuration is ready after 0.245 seconds.
[3/20/17 15:29:32:615 CDT] 0000003f id=         com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPChannel                    I CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host 127.0.0.1  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 8080.
[3/20/17 15:29:34:449 CDT] 0000001d id=         com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSID0108I: JMS server has started.  
[3/20/17 15:29:34:487 CDT] 0000001d id=         com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPChannel                    I CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel wasJmsEndpoint480 has been started and is now listening for requests on host 127.0.0.1  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 7276.
[3/20/17 15:29:34:619 CDT] 0000001d id=         com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1001I: WebSphere Dynamic Cache instance named baseCache initialized successfully.
[3/20/17 15:29:34:620 CDT] 0000001d id=         com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1071I: The cache provider default is being used.
[3/20/17 15:29:34:620 CDT] 0000001d id=         com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
[3/20/17 15:29:35:318 CDT] 0000005d id=         com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:8080/SpringProject/
[3/20/17 15:29:35:322 CDT] 0000005d id=         com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0001I: Application SpringProject started in 0.302 seconds.
[3/20/17 15:29:35:328 CDT] 00000027 id=         com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [mdb-3.2, localConnector-1.0, webProfile-7.0, json-1.0, jaxrs-2.0, appSecurity-2.0, jpa-2.1, jaspic-1.1, distributedMap-1.0, jaxb-2.2, jaxws-2.2, ssl-1.0, jdbc-4.1, managedBeans-1.0, jsf-2.2, appClientSupport-1.0, jacc-1.5, ejbHome-3.2, wasJmsClient-2.0, cdi-1.2, wasJmsSecurity-1.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, ejbRemote-3.2, javaMail-1.5, batch-1.0, j2eeManagement-1.1, websocket-1.1, el-3.0, beanValidation-1.1, ejbPersistentTimer-3.2, jca-1.7, wasJmsServer-1.0, servlet-3.1, ejb-3.2, jsp-2.3, jndi-1.0, jsonp-1.0, concurrent-1.0, ejbLite-3.2, jcaInboundSecurity-1.0, javaee-7.0].
[3/20/17 15:29:35:329 CDT] 00000027 id=         com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0011I: The server server2 is ready to run a smarter planet.
 [3/20/17 15:29:36:368 CDT] 0000006b id=         com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
[3/20/17 15:29:44:733 CDT] 00000045 id=         ibm.ws.transport.iiop.security.AbstractCsiv2SubsystemFactory E CWWKS9582E: The [defaultSSLConfig] sslRef attributes required by the orb element with the defaultOrb id have not been resolved within 10 seconds. As a result, the applications will not start. Ensure that you have included a keyStore element and that Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) is configured correctly. If the sslRef is defaultSSLConfig, then add a keyStore element with the id defaultKeyStore and a password.
```

This is my project structure

[image]

***EDIT-4***
I have the below project facets

[image]

I have jdk 7

[image]

Comment: verify context root in your server.xml

Comment: <webApplication id="SpringProject" contextRoot = "SpringProject" location="SpringProject.war" name="SpringProject"/>

Comment: what if you try - http://localhost:8080/SpringProject/   ?

Comment: I see this on browser---  Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /

Comment: can you post your web.xml?

Comment: There is no web.xml file.. I have this in maven instead of web.xml.<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
     <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
      <warName>SpringProject</warName>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>

Comment: can you post your WAR-inner structure please? and if possible the last parts of the websphere-log during startup. Just to verify the app has been successfully started.

Comment: @The86Freak .. Please look at EDIT-3

Comment: ok, log seems fine, even though, I'm just wondering: are you using the Liberty-Profile? (because you wrote: "I am using websphere 8.5.5.9" - there are some differences between Liberty and websphere in behaviour especially with WARs).

I was just wondering about the WAR inner content, if everything is at the place where it should be, when opening it with an archiver like 7zip etc. Can you access a file like: 
```http://localhost:8080/SpringProject/css/style.css```
?
If that does work, would you mind adding a web.xml and a beans.xml by hand?

Comment: One More thing I'm wondering: there's no Spring-start-log message in the log. Shouldn't there be one?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you should tell spring where to fine the configuration class;
did you try the following:

```
package com.spring.config;
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {  

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    // Create the 'root' Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.scan("com.spring");
    rootContext.setConfigLocations(YOUR SPRING CFG FULL QUALIFIED CLASSES );

    // Manages the lifecycle of the root application context
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    // Declare dispatcher servlet. Handles requests into the application
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
            new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}
}
```

Try to give a look here [AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html) and here [AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.html#setConfigLocation-java.lang.String-)

Comment: I added this line It didn't work:      rootContext.setConfigLocations("com.spring.config.WebAppContextConfig" );

Comment: Here https://github.com/angeloimm/stackoverflow/tree/master/SpringStack you can find a simple sample done by using your classes. I used tomcat 8.5 and all works pretty good. The access URL is http://localhost:8080/SpringStack/

Comment: Hi.. I downloaded your code and tried locally .. I have jdk 7 and websphere liberty profile.. So I deleted your settings and classpath files. and please look at my EDIT -4. Wondering if it has to to with my project facets

Comment: Also can you please share if you have any thing in server.xml inside tomcat 8.5

Comment: @javaMan: it is a maven project... so maven should be enough to create the war artifact; i have nothing special in server.xml. I'm wondering if your AS supports servlet 3.X specification

Comment: @javaMan: maybe this can be usefull https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_servlet-3.0.html

Comment: It didn't work. I added these features and tried:    <featureManager>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
          <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
         <feature>jaxb-2.2</feature>
    </featureManager>

Comment: Strange. Did you add also com.ibm.websphere.appserver.servlet-3.0; type="osgi.subsystem.feature" in the manifest of the webb app (at least i guess so by reading the IBM link)

Answer (score 1):

This might be causing issue , Please change it

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/statuscheck", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String getStatusCheck() {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

To

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/statuscheck", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getStatusCheck() {
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```